# php permission levels to view lower level users

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have a problem I just cannot figure out. I am writing an app for my place of work to manage and plan shift patterns and holidays. There are 4 levels of user:

> Level 1 - User
>   Level 2 - Manager
>   Level 3 - Senior Manager
>   Level 4 - Admin

I currently use bitwise type permission to authorise who can access what on the app and this is working fine. What I want now is to allow a user or a higher level to edit and authorise data from users of a lower level. So basically a manager can authorise a user and a Senior manager can authorise both a user and manager. The permissions are store in a single field in the following format.

> User - 000
>   Manager - 001
>   Senior Manager - 011
>   Admin - 111

So with this I can search the DB for any user that has a permission set less than the current users permission.

Except...

Here's the problem.

I have a trusted manager who I want to be an admin to add users and manage the system but I don't want them to be able to authorise any one but users data?

I know I tend to waffle but does anyone have any ideas on this??

Many Thanks,

Gav.

Comment: I think you're talking about a permissions and roles table. Each role or "level" as you say has different permissions. Look at pivot tables - http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables

Comment: As you're already storing permissions with a binary you may work on  a bitwise accreditation. a check on `user level & authorization === authorization` would do having a admin only perm with a value of 100 for exemple which would not had same rights as the Senior Manager level ... but @Mike answer is maybe more laravel friendly

Comment: I not sure this will help Mike. The permissions are already in the database. OK, maybe not the best way but they are there. The problem is how to turn the permissions into a SQL query to return users below you.